# How to specify the type of Primary Key as String in jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

By default, jhipster create entity with id as long/int. I would like to use "String" for id. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps:

1. Of course the property type in the Java class must be changed to String (and also update the getter and setter for that property).
2. Then create a Liquibase changeset that modifies the data type to String. See: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/modify_data_type.html

If there are foreign keys that depend on this id, then makes it a bit more complicated because the fk's will need to be dropped and recreated after the columns have been changed to String.

Take a look at src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog to see how to set up a changeset consistent with the jhipster. I usually copy an existing changeset, give it a new file name so that it is the last file in the directory (so you can see a chronological sequence of changes), and update the changeset id.

Then, the changeset must also be added to src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml so that it is activated on the next app start.